# Should the browser cache HTTP Auth credentials sent via Ajax?

Tags: javascript, http, xmlhttprequest

I am building a static website with restricted access. I have configured the server to protect a subfolder (say www.example.com/restricted) with HTTP Basic Auth.
Now, I do not want to use the standard browser popup for the login, since it's ugly and does not remember the password across sessions. And it's ugly, did I mention that? =)

So, I am showing a html form, and try to do the authentication via JavaScript (here, with help of jQuery, but the "raw" version showed the same behaviour). The function I am calling looks like

```
try_login = function(username, password){
  $.ajax({
      url: '/restricted/login.token',
      method: 'GET',
      beforeSend: function(request) {
          request.setRequestHeader(
             'Authorization', 
             'Basic ' + Base64.encode(username + ':' + password));
      },
      success: function () { window.location='/restricted/'; },
      error: function () { $('#error_message').text("Wrong password."); }});
```

}

Now, the authentication works for the ajax request. "login.token" is served correctly with status code 200 if I use the correct username and password, and I get a 401 if I don't.

But the browser (I tested Chrome 28 and IE 10) asks again for the credentials following the redirect in the success callback. It does not seem to save the credentials.

Am I doing something wrong, or is this indeed the expected behaviour? If it is, is there a way to cheat? I really think the browser popup is ugly.

Since this is a static site, any authentication scheme required active server-side code is unfortunately not usable here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to send the Authorization header with each request.

Try this approach - [How to use Basic Auth with jQuery and AJAX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5507234/how-to-use-basic-auth-and-jquery-and-ajax)